# 2D game animation android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-animation

I am new in android and specially with canvas. I want to develop small 2D game. In that game i want to display something like object is running on the ground and background is continuously changing. But I am not finding the right way to start my assignment.I want some sample project example. Please guide me. How can I change my background?

Answer (score 3):

As a JavaScript enthusiastic i follow this-
[This may help you](http://digipiph.com/blog/creating-sprite-character-movement-javascript-and-jquery-ver-12)

Links you can start at-

[Keydown activities](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/4Xfdc/6/)

[Ball under radial canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/cggkp/)

[Mouse move under canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/U4nd2/5/)

Canvas allows you to create javascript based games, as a beginner there is no better way than using canvas for animations.
Just create canvas-

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

And start exploring.

Comment: http://unity3D.com is a tool like maya 3D, you can create your own script based games here, without using much complications of javascript. You can also start here if you are a beginner.

Comment: But if i want to start using eclipse then which is the better way to start?

Answer (score 3):

You can use AndEngine which is a open source 2D game engine. This is the official website

http://www.andengine.org/

and for tutorials, this is a good source :- http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/

Comment: Sorry for argument but with this tutorial he can't learn basic of game programming.

Answer (score 1):

From start you should learn basic of gaming programming..
Please start with bouncing ball and space shooter game. with JavaScript and canvas with html5.

Take help from

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

http://sixrevisions.com/html/bouncing-a-ball-around-with-html5-and-javascript/

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-ball-physics/

http://asgaard.co.uk/misc/html5canvas.php

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you aren't sure how to start coding such a game, then this will help you a lot.

[Simple Game-loop](http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/)

As it says, it gives you skeleton code for a basic Android game loop using SurfaceView and explains what's happening pretty well.

Hope it help - good luck!